# Method does not override method from its superclass error

Tags: android

Only this `@Override` method is getting an error. Although, every other `@Override` method is fine. I am not getting the same error on those.

Any help is appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.Register) {
        createAccount( mEmailView.getText().toString(), mPasswordView.getText().toString() );
    } else if (i == R.id.Login){
        Intent in = new Intent( LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity2.class );
        startActivity(in);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some more code.

Comment: Is this in  an anonymous View.OnClickListener?  Because you're calling startActivity, which doesn't exist on a View class.  If you're putting this directly in an Activity its right-  you aren't overriding a function (Activity does not have an onClick).

Comment: @GabeSechan i think its a view class, there you have the whole code, but how do I fix that though?

Comment: Can you provide the whole code? With this it is difficult to find the error.

Comment: @Gourav There you go man, another thing, how do I make the "register" button start a new activity?

Comment: Just remove the "@Override" annotation. That annotation should not be there for that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving a warning because the `@Override` annotation is wrongly inserted on that method.

There's no `OnClick(View v)` method on parent class. So, you can't override a method that does not exist on parent class.

Just remove the `@Override` and that warning should go:

```
// @Override --> Remove this
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.Register) {
        createAccount( mEmailView.getText().toString(), mPasswordView.getText().toString() );
    } else if (i == R.id.Login){
        Intent in = new Intent( LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity2.class );
        startActivity(in);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement an onClickListener.
You should implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface in your activity.

```
public class YourActivityName extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Then in the `onCreate()` method you can use `yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);`

As I read in the comments, to start an activity from the register button do this outside onCreate:

```
Button registerBtn;
```

Inside `onCreate` method do this:

```
registerBtn=findViewById(R.id.register);
registerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Inside `onClick` method do this:

```
if(v.equals(registerBtn))
{
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```